# Reading the Excel file uploaded by postman in Spring boot WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a requirement in which I need to upload a single excel file via postman request
and read all the rows of that excel file using spring boot WebFlux.

I wanted to know is there any way to do this?

I am using spring boot version 2.3.9 and Java 1.8.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create an Endpoint that through a POST request, accepts the `.xlsx` file, then use Apache POI to read each row of the Excel file.

Step 1:

Creation of the Endpoint which accepts `MultiartFiles`. [This](https://technicalsand.com/spring-boot-multipart-file-upload-example-postman/) tutorial explains it all, even using `Postman`.

Step 2:

After you got the file in your Back-End, you're gonna want to process it. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) comes to help here. First of all, include it to your project by adding this in the `pom` :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is a simple snippet on how to read a file with Apache Poi:

```java
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = // the file that you get from the request, transformed into a FileInputStream
 
            //Creation of the Workbook that holds as reference the Excel file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
 
            //Getting the first sheet of the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 
            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                 
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly, other cell types exist, you may want to check them out
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
            file.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This is not webflux, not leveraging the webflux ecosystem. And the tutorial linked is not webflux either.

Comment: @Toerktumlare do you know a way to read Excel files using pure WebFlux?